# selector for button inside collectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, selector

This is driving me nuts, I've been reading SO for hours and tried everything and cant get this button selector to work.  This shouldn't be difficult.

Inside CellForItemAt i have set the button tag and try call the button.

```
cell.deleteCellButton.tag = indexPath.item
cell.deleteCellButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteCellButtonTapped(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

I've tried (_:), "deleteCellButtonTapped:", and any other number of parenthesis combinations and i still get unrecognised selector.  i don't know why autocomplete recommends (sender:) I've never seen this before.

then my button function:

```
func deleteCellButtonTapped(sender: UIButton!) {
    self.packArray.remove(at: sender.tag)
        print(packArray.count)
    self.outerCollectionView.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item: sender.tag, section: 0)])

    self.outerCollectionView.reloadData()
    self.outerCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: #selector(self. deleteCellButtonTapped(sender:)) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Swift 3, and `func deleteCellButtonTapped(sender: UIButton!)` is in the same class:

```
addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteCellButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Refering the **selector method** from it's class works for me.

What you can do is access selector method prefixing by it's **class name**.

I assume your class name is `MyClassViewController`. And you code will look like:

```
class MyClassViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    .... // Other implementation methods

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        ....// create cell object and dequeue

        cell.deleteCellButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyClassViewController.deleteCellButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }

    func deleteCellButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
         // your method implementation
          print("Selector method called")
    }
}
```

Hope this works fine